# Django serializing associated objects

Tags: django, python-3.x

I've the following Location and User model.

```
class Location(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    latitude = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    longitude = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    mobile = PhoneNumberField(null=True)
    username = models.CharField(null=True, unique=True, max_length=255)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_mobile_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

These are the respective Serializers.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = (
            'id', 'email', 'mobile', 'username', 'full_name', 'password', 'is_active', 'is_mobile_verified',
        )



class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)

        class Meta:
            model = models.Location
            fields = ('id', 'country', 'city', 'longitude', 'latitude')
```

Now I'm serializing and outputting data like this.

```
return Response(UserSerializer(user).data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

My question is how can I return user data with his location using the two serializers together?

Answer (score 1):

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    location = LocationSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = (
            'id', 'email', 'mobile', 'username', 'full_name', 'password', 'is_active', 'is_mobile_verified', 'location'
        )



class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)

        class Meta:
            model = models.Location
            fields = ('id', 'country', 'city', 'longitude', 'latitude')
```